# Erro ao colocar um componente no form Delphi Berlin

Tags: delphi

Tenho os fontes de um antigo componente de xadrez em Delphi. Fiz a migração do mesmo para o Berlin. Depois de compilar e instalar tudo ok. Porem, um dos componentes apresenta problemas quando eu o insiro no form, gerando um erro.

Esse componente, derivado da classe TPanel, serve para visualizar a escrita das partidas. O erro:

***"Acces violation at address 24365BF2 in module "ChessBoard.bpl". Write of address 0000005C".***

**Detalhes:**

> [24365BF2]{ChessBoard.bpl}
>   Notation.TNotation.$bctr$qqrp25System.Classes.TComponent (Line 1020,
>   "Notation.pas" + 61) + $15 [500601B8]{rtl240.bpl  }
>   System.TMonitor.Destroy (Line 18102, "System.pas" + 0) + $0
>   [5005F839]{rtl240.bpl  } System.TObject.CleanupInstance (Line 16698,
>   "System.pas" + 37) + $0 [5005A1C9]{rtl240.bpl  } System.@ReallocMem
>   (Line 4736, "System.pas" + 21) + $0 [50065346]{rtl240.bpl  }
>   System.DynArraySetLength (Line 34277, "System.pas" + 104) + $13
>   [5005A1FB]{rtl240.bpl  } System.@ReallocMem (Line 4806, "System.pas" +
>   91) + $0 [50065346]{rtl240.bpl  } System.DynArraySetLength (Line
>   34277, "System.pas" + 104) + $13 [50AA6857]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.AlignControl (Line 9014, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   1) + $3 [50065346]{rtl240.bpl  } System.DynArraySetLength (Line 34277,
>   "System.pas" + 104) + $13 [50AA1154]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TControl.RequestAlign (Line 5555, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1)
>   + $1 [50AA995F]{vcl240.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.RequestAlign (Line 10825, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 11) + $3 [50AA8675]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10143, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   158) + $6 [5005FBE2]{rtl240.bpl  } System.@CallDynaInst (Line 17133,
>   "System.pas" + 4) + $0 [50155C39]{rtl240.bpl  }
>   System.Classes.TInterfacedPersistent.AfterConstruction (Line 5555,
>   "System.Classes.pas" + 2) + $6 [5005FF2D]{rtl240.bpl  }
>   System.@AfterConstruction (Line 17839, "System.pas" + 2) + $5
>   [50159051]{rtl240.bpl  } System.Classes.TStringList.Create (Line 7244,
>   "System.Classes.pas" + 2) + $6 [24365BE4]{ChessBoard.bpl}
>   Notation.TNotation.$bctr$qqrp25System.Classes.TComponent (Line 1020,
>   "Notation.pas" + 61) + $7 [21F9019B]{delphicoreide240.bpl}
>   CompPalMgr.TComponentPalettePageItemDelegate.CreateComponent (Line
>   2755, "CompPalMgr.pas" + 2) + $7 [2129C683]{designide240.bpl}
>   ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.DoCreateComponent (Line 2491,
>   "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 28) + $17 [212A2950]{designide240.bpl}
>   ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateCurrentComponent (Line 4792,
>   "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 2) + $34 [212BDD82]{designide240.bpl}
>   Surface.TDesignSurface.CreateItem (Line 203, "Surface.pas" + 1) + $11
>   [2126294A]{designide240.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.DoDragCreate (Line
>   802, "Designer.pas" + 1) + $F [2126324C]{designide240.bpl}
>   Designer.TDesigner.DragEnd (Line 988, "Designer.pas" + 19) + $3
>   [21265864]{designide240.bpl} Designer.TDesigner.MouseUp (Line 1776,
>   "Designer.pas" + 1) + $2 [525BFB36]{vcldesigner240.bpl}
>   VCLSurface.MouseEvent (Line 3257, "VCLSurface.pas" + 45) + $11
>   [500604A7]{rtl240.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 18292,
>   "System.pas" + 2) + $7 [525C072B]{vcldesigner240.bpl}
>   VCLSurface.TVclDesignSurface.IsDesignMsg (Line 3518, "VCLSurface.pas"
>   + 48) + $6 [5005FA96]{rtl240.bpl  } System.@IsClass (Line 16965, "System.pas" + 1) + $8 [50AA38AF]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7226, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 4) +
>   $21 [0D9C514C]{TrackingSystem240.bpl} TrackingSystemHelp.CBTHookProc
>   (Line 211, "TrackingSystemHelp.pas" + 27) + $F [50AA7E83]{vcl240.bpl 
>   } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9906,
>   "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $9 [50AA8675]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10143, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   158) + $6 [50BE5565]{vcl240.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line
>   4523, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 209) + $5 [525C9A03]{vcldesigner240.bpl}
>   VCLFormContainer.TControlSizer.ControlWndProc (Line 344,
>   "VCLFormContainer.pas" + 33) + $C [50AA7C94]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9850, "Vcl.Controls.pas" +
>   3) + $6 [50170D28]{rtl240.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line
>   17179, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0 [50BEEC8F]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10534, "Vcl.Forms.pas" +
>   23) + $1 [50BEECD2]{vcl240.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage
>   (Line 10564, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4 [50BEF005]{vcl240.bpl  }
>   Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10702, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3

Alguém pode ajudar? Deve ser coisa simples. Qualquer coisa posto o fonte desse componente.

Comment: Posta..........

Comment: João, um primeiro teste que você pode fazer, é criar um projeto sem dependência de packages de terceiros, adicionar os fontes do projeto de xadrez no seu projeto e criar o componente em uma tela em tempo de execução, se a exceção acontecer, você conseguiria debugar o projeto. Se desta maneira funcionar, você precisa buscar no código do componente as coisas específicas de design time.